# Converting html table to string using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've got some html in a string and I need to extract a table from it. So, for example, my htmlString variable contains (:

```
<html><head>....some head stuff</head><body><table>.... some table stuff</table>.... other body stuff</body></html>
```

So, what I have tried is the following:
(typed, not copied, so there may be typos)

var table       = $( '' ).append( htmlString ).find( 'table' ).get();

If I view my table variable, I do see:

```
[<table>...</table>]
```

so, I believe I am extracting the table from the html string correctly.

Now, to convert this back to a string, I do the following:

```
var tableString = $( table[0] ).html();
```

and I get back:

```
<tbody> ... the table stuff ... </tbody>
```

but, what I want is:

```
<table> ... the table stuff ... </table>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have an easy way to get an element's "outerHTML". Instead of

```
var tableString = $( table[0] ).html();
```

you can do

```
var tableString = $(table[0]).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
```

or, if you're not worried about compatibility with really old browsers:

```
var tableString = $(table[0])[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: I believe there are other good answers here, but this is the one I used.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
$( table[0] )[0].outerHTML
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript version: http://jsfiddle.net/Zahmu/

```
var html = "<div><table><tbody></tbody></table></div>";

var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
wrapper.innerHTML = html;

var table = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
alert(table.outerHTML);
```

jQuery isn't giving you much in this case. You might benefit from using it locate the table element with a more complex source string, but the crux of the solution is `outerHTML`.